# Get Value from a curl command output

Tags: json, curl

I have below 2 format for output which is an output of curl command the 1st one is from the swagger site and the 2nd is when I run the curl from linux.

I want to get the value for **data** fields in both the cases like the current value of **data** is **0** so it should be coming as **0** without double quotes.

how can we extract it in linux :

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "responseData": {
    "data": [
      "0"
    ]
  },
  "error": null
}
```

OR

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","responseData":{"data":["0"]},"error":null}
```

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/bash_jq_command/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for that e.g. `jq` command with `-r` (or `--raw-output`) flag as follows:
*(since the value of `data` is an `array` get e.g. the first element with `[0]`)*

```bash
curl https://server.com/rest-api/foo | jq -r '.responseData.data[0]'

# Test:
echo '{"status":"SUCCESS","responseData":{"data":["0"]},"error":null}'| jq -r '.responseData.data[0]'
# Output:
0
```

Comment: OP: This is the correct answer. The format you are getting back is called JSON, and you always want to use a tool like `jq` to parse it. Trying to parse structured data like JSON or HTML yourself with grep or awk is error-prone at best.

Answer (score -1):

You could try with `sed` - assuming the format is consistent - something like this

```
curl https://server.com/rest-api/foo | sed -r 's/^.*data\":\[\"(.*)\"].*$/\1/'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does NOT work if the ```data``` array has more then 1 values. E.g. ```echo '{"status":"SUCCESS","responseData":{"data":["0","1"]},"error":null}'| sed -r 's/^.*data\":\[\"(.*)\"].*$/\1/'```, the RESULT: ```0", "1```.